# Anagrams of the word "MOOC".

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The given word is: `MOOC`. We have to find the anagrams.

According to the formula, the answer is, $\frac{4!}{2!} = 12$

However, if I want to see it from a different perspective, I can't find the correct answer:

```
_,_,_,_
```

I have 4 positions to fill up.

Since there are 3 unique characters, the 1st position can be filled up in 3 ways, and the 2nd position can be filled up in 2 ways. The last 2 positions can be filled up in 1 way as there are 2 `O`s. Therefore, I have $3*2 = 6$.

This is not the correct answer.

What am I missing?

Comment: Imagine that the first letter is an O, then you still have 3 ways of choosing the second letter.

Comment: Why not just count them?  Then work through your argument using the explicit list of possibilities and see where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the first position can be filled in 3 different ways. If there is an O in the first position, the positions left can be filled in $3! = \textbf{6}$ ways. If it isn't an O, take a look at the second position. If the second position is an O, you have 2 ways to fill the last two, and 2 ways to start the word, which is $2*2 = \textbf{4}$. If the second place isn't an O too, there are $\textbf{2}$ ways you can fill the first too, namely MC and CM, and 1 way to fill the last 2. Sum these all up, and you get $2+4+6 = 12$.

Comment: I am not concerned about division. I am concerned about describing the whole situation only using logic and multiplication.

Comment: It's in the first paragraph, if the first letter is O, you'll still have 3 letters to fill the next space.